# Atlas MongoDB SSH Tunnel hostname mismatch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to setup an SSH tunnel to a mongoDB cluster hosted In Atlas. I setup the tunnel with the below command

```
ssh -i <key_file> -N -L <localport>:<atlas_node_hostname>:<atlas_port> <remote_user>@<remote_ip>
```

And added the atlas_node_hostname in

> /etc/hosts

From the machine where I created the SSH tunnel, I can connect to atlas db with the atlas_node_hostname mentioned in the string.

```
mongo --ssl "mongodb://<username>:<password>@<atlas_node_hostname>:<ssh_tunnel_local_port>/<db_name>?authSource=admin"
```

But I want to connect using 127.0.0.1 instead of the atlas_node_hostname, this is so that I can give devs access only to the machine where the tunnel is running and they can connect to the DB.

```
mongo --ssl "mongodb://<username>:<password>@<127.0.0.1:<ssh_tunnel_local_port>/<db_name>?authSource=admin"
```

But with the above attempt I get the below error

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27779, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: The server certificate does not match the host name. Hostname: 127.0.0.1 does not match SAN(s): *.345ed5412fd76fb84cd13794.utkqs.mongodb.net, *.utkqs.mesh.mongodb.net, *.utkqs.mongodb.net, CN: *.utkqs.mongodb.net :
```

Is there any way I can get it working with the 127.0.0.1 instead of giving the atlas_node_hostname? Or any tool that can proxy Atlas MongoDB?